# Bash git autodeploy war

Tags: java, git, bash, maven, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to make a git hook to auto deploy my war's . I've created a bash script to create the repository , build with Maven and auto deploy the war to the jetty webapps folder

```
3) echo "Creating new Maven (Java) repository"
    echo "Please enter a project name : "
    read REPO
    if [ -n $REPO ]; then
        if [ -d /home/$GITUSER/webapps/$REPO ]; then
            echo "Destination deployment directory already exists"
        else
            echo "Creating new repository deployment directory"
            mkdir /home/$GITUSER/webapps/$REPO
            echo "Creating new repository"
            mkdir /git/$REPO.git && cd /git/$REPO.git && git init --bare --shared
            echo "Please enter a description for the repository or hit return for none"
            read DESC
            if [ -n "$DESC" ]; then
                cat /dev/null > /git/$REPO.git/description
                echo "$DESC" > /git/$REPO.git/description
            fi
            echo "Creating repository deployment hook"
            touch /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive 
            echo "#!/bin/bash\n" >> /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive
            echo "git --work-tree=/home/$GITUSER/webapps/$REPO --git-dir=/git/$REPO.git checkout -f" >> /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive
            echo "cd /home/$GITUSER/webapps/$REPO && mvn package" >> /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive "\n"
            echo "cp find /home/$GITUSER/webapps/$REPO/target/*.war /opt/jetty/webapps/$REPO.war" >> /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive
            chmod +x /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive
            echo "Repository created successfuly"
            echo "Use git clone ssh://$GITUSER@$GITDOMAIN:$GITPORT/git/$REPO.git"
            echo "Thank you !"
            exit
        fi
    else
        echo "Project name cannot be empty"         
    fi;;
```

the problem is at this line where I'm trying to copy the war

```
echo "cp find /home/$GITUSER/webapps/$REPO/target/*.war /opt/jetty/webapps/$REPO.war" >> /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive
```

can you please give me an advice ? 
Thanks !

Comment: `[ -n $REPO ]` will return true if you receive no input, try it. You want `[ -n "$REPO" ]`. In general always quote your variables.

Comment: What is the problem on that line? Is it not working? Is that line in the hook not working later? What?

Comment: There's no reason to `cat /dev/null > /git/$REPO.git/description` before echoing the contents to the file. Similarly no reason to `touch /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive` before sending content to it.

Comment: That line is not in the post - receive hook I'm trying to put it there but instead it gets executed by bash before it is written in the file . What I've pasted is the part of my "external" script which creates the hook so the problem is that the command is executed before the sources are available from the repo .

Comment: The line `echo "cp find /home/$GITUSER/webapps/$REPO/target/*.war /opt/jetty/webapps/$REPO.war" >> /git/$REPO.git/hooks/post-receive` is **not** running the `cp` command at that point. You do have a strange/stray `"\n"` on the end of the line before that line though which could certainly be confusing some things. What output are you seeing from your script *exactly*? (What if you add `set -x` to the top of that block?)

Comment: Thank you guys for all your answers , I think that I have not ask the question the right way this is my bash script http://pastebin.com/yvjKNaAa I use this script to create new repositories . everything works fine until I push the sources to the repository this is my output remote:
remote: [INFO] Total time: 11.616s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 06 11:53:05 EET 2014
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/34M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: cp: target `/opt/jetty/webapps/test.war' is not a directory

Comment: and this is how my hook looks like http://pastebin.com/HPpN6UFM

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy multiple files to a single file.

Your `cp` line, and I'm not sure why I didn't notice this before, is `cp find /path/to/*.war /path/to/file.war`.

Which has a number of problems.

`find` isn't doing anything useful there (it is being seen as a file to copy).

The output target is a file (not a directory).

You need to figure out what you *actually* want to be doing there and fix that copy line.

Something like `cp /home/paul/webapps/test/target/*.war /opt/jetty/webapps/test` perhaps?

Comment: But I want the .war to have the same name as the repository and I don't know the original file name . This is my problem

Comment: @PaulDumitru If `/home/paul/webapps/test/target/*.war` will only ever match one file then just remove the erroneous `find` from that line and it should work. But it will break if that glob ever matches more than one file.

Comment: Thanks I will try to do as you say